# Selenium with if-else statements not working

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, pylance

I am trying to open a webpage with selenium at a specific time, but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    PATH = "chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    ct = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")

    if ct == 8:55:
        driver.get("https://webpage.com/")
    else:
        print("Waiting for time to be 8:55...")
        time.sleep(100)
```

Expected: If the current time is 8:55, it has to open the webpage "https://webpage.com/", or else it should print the text "Waiting for the time to be 8:55" and sleep for 100 seconds.

Actual Result: The code is returning these errors:

```
Expected expression. Pylance [11, 19]
Type annotation not supported for this type of expression. Pylance [11, 19]
Unexpected indentation. Pylance [12, 9]
Unindent not expected. Pylance [15, 24]
Expected expression. Pylance [15, 24]
Statements must be separated by newlines or semicolons. Pylance [15, 24]
```

I am using Visual Studio Code as my IDE, and I have selenium installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if ct == 8:55:` is a syntax error. You probably wanted to write

```
if ct == "08:55":
```

As a side note if you sleep for 100 seconds at, say, `08:54:50` it will be `08:56:30` when you wake up and you will miss your window. You should sleep less than 1 minute.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm stupid- I forgot to add a link in the ```driver.get("")``` statement. It is working fine now. I also added a ```driver.quit()``` in the ```else``` statement and I have put ```time.sleep(25)``` instead of ```time.sleep(100)``` so that it doesn't start spamming opening windows.